# Worry to delete Read replica RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, aws, read-only-database, data-loss

I created a read replica from RDS , and I do want to delete it.

I am so worry about affecting the origin RDS which is in PROD .

- Is it recommended to take snapshots before deletion of read replica instance ?
- Or it is a safe action , known that AWS console shows the screen when I click on delete?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Taking a snapshot is never a bad idea when making changes in a production environment.

That said, it should be safe to delete a replica in RDS as long as you don't have any service connected to it.